# Rails - display relationship data but with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models

1. Job (`belongs_to :hiring_procedure`)
2. Hiring Procedure (`has_many :jobs, has_many :hiring_procedure_stages`)
3. Hiring Procedure Stage (`belongs_to :hiring_procedure`)

This means inside the view where I am displaying a job i can access different hiring stages as following which is working fine.

```
job.hiring_procedure.hiring_procedure_stages
```

My question is, the above code will return all stages, what if i only want stages where the `deleted` column of model `hiring_procedure_stage` is `f`

I am actually displaying different stages in a drop down menu for the user to select and i do not want the user to see the deleted stages (deleted means where the deleted value is `t` for model `hiring_procedure_stage` , its a boolean)

```
<%= select_tag 
  'application_stage',
   options_for_select(
   job.hiring_procedure.hiring_procedure_stages.map{ |p|[p.name, p.id] }, 
   hiring_procedure_stage_id
),%>
```

Is there a way to achieve this in view or its better to put this logic inside the controller in another variable and access that in view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a scope in **hiring_procedure_stage.rb** model

```
scope :active, -> { where(deleted: false) }
```

And now you can use the above scope as:

```
job.hiring_procedure.hiring_procedure_stages.active
```

This will only return you `hiring_procedure_stages` where `deleted is false`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is defining the relationship with that *scope*, so it will **always** consider stages that are not deleted.

To do so add the *scope* to the association:

```
class HiringProcedure < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :hiring_procedure_stages, -> { where(deleted: false) }
end
```

And every time you use

```
hiring_procedure.hiring_procedure_stages
```

you will get all stages that are not deleted.

Of course this solution is recommended only if you will never try to get stages that are deleted.

Comment: Thanks, this is a neat solution as well.